# A few basic questions about encoding, unicode and stdout

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Say I do this:

```
>>> 'é'        #1
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> u'é'       #2
u'\xe9'
>>> print u'é' #3
é
```

This is my understanding:

1. When I pasted `'é'` into my Python session, a bytearray
   containing 2 bytes somehow landed in to `stdin`, which Python
   read from. The same bytes are sent to `stdout` and displayed in hexadecimal form.
2. This time Python has to decode the bytes: it reads `sys.stdin.encoding`, finds `utf-8`, and decodes the 2 bytes into unicode. Then I am not sure what happens. Can we send a unicode string to `stdout`? Or maybe Python takes the hexadeximal representation of the unicode code point, encodes it in `utf-8` and sends to `stdout`?
3. Python decodes the 2 bytes into unicode. Then `print` encodes it again in `utf-8` and sends the result to `stdout`.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python interactive interpreter echos the result of any expression except if that result is `None`. Echoing always uses the [`repr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to create a useable representation. Under the hood, objects have a [`__repr__` special method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) that does all the hard work here.

For strings, a value is printed that can be used directly in Python again to recreate the string, and any non-printable, non-ASCII bytes are represented with an escape sequence. Newlines become `\n`, for example, and the two UTF-8 bytes for `é` are represented with the `\xhh` hex escape.

Thus, for point 1, Python indeed received two bytes from the terminal, stored those in a string, and the *representation* of the string consists of the characters `'`, `\`, `x`, `c`, `3`, etc. If you pasted that back into Python, you'd get the same string value again.

For 2., you created a Unicode string object. The terminal sent two UTF-8 bytes, but you now told Python to parse a `u'..'` string literal, which is indeed decoded by using `sys.stdin.encoding`.

The representation for a Unicode string object is another string literal, prefixed with `u` to show it is a Unicode string, not a regular string. Unicode codepoints in the range U+0080 through to U+00FF (the Latin 1 range) are represented by the `\xhh` escape code. `é` is [Unicode codepoint U+00E9](http://codepoints.net/U+00e9), so is represented by `\xe9`. Codepoints from U+0100 up to U+FFFF use the `\uhhhh` representation, for higher codepoints `\Uhhhhhhhh` is used.

Again, you can copy this representation, paste it back into Python and get the exact same value again.

`print` writes directly to `sys.stdout`, and if you give `print` a Unicode string object, will use `sys.stdout.encoding` to first encode the Unicode string value to a bytestring before writing it to `sys.stdout`.